# Flutter build issue apk build fail

Tags: android, flutter

I am getting the following issue while building the apk :

/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.3.3/lib/src/structs.g.dart:661:31: Error: Member not found: 'UnicodeChar'.
int get UnicodeChar => Char.UnicodeChar;
^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.3.3/lib/src/structs.g.dart:662:38: Error: Setter not found: 'UnicodeChar'.
set UnicodeChar(int value) => Char.UnicodeChar = value;
^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.3.3/lib/src/structs.g.dart:664:29: Error: Member not found: 'AsciiChar'.
int get AsciiChar => Char.AsciiChar;
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.3.3/lib/src/structs.g.dart:665:36: Error: Setter not found: 'AsciiChar'.
set AsciiChar(int value) => Char.AsciiChar = value;
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_calendar_carousel-1.5.3/lib/flutter_calendar_carousel.dart:424:16: Error: The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the c
lass '_CalendarState'.

- '_CalendarState' is from 'package:flutter_calendar_carousel/flutter_calendar_carousel.dart' ('/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_calendar_carousel-1.5.3/
  lib/flutter_calendar_carousel.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FlatButton'.
  child: FlatButton(
  ^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_calendar_carousel-1.5.3/lib/src/calendar_header.dart:46:32: Error: The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the class 'C
  alendarHeader'.
- 'CalendarHeader' is from 'package:flutter_calendar_carousel/src/calendar_header.dart' ('/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_calendar_carousel-1.5.3/lib/sr
  c/calendar_header.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FlatButton'.
  Widget _headerTouchable() => FlatButton(
  ^^^^^^^^^^

  ```
    *********************************************************
  ```

WARNING: This version of flutter_webview_plugin will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
See https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/android/androidx-migration for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
*********************************************************

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 20s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           81.7s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Link to the project source code - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GaNcymRQ1SmQDln-0JpsoEG_9Gy3sOn7?usp=sharing

Please help as soon as possible.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

By looking at this section of error, your dependencies might not be compatible with AndroidX.

> WARNING: This version of flutter_webview_plugin will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/issues/500) you need to migrate to AndroidX. To migrate follow these steps -

1 - Open android directory with Android Studio 3.2+.

2 - Click on Refactor then migrate to AndroidX.

[image]

After that add these to the gradle.properties file in the android directory.

```
android.useAndroidX=true 
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: Migrate to Android X option is not highlighted.

Comment: Also I already added the given two lines